# How does DDL replication work in AWS DMS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-dms

Could you please explain how DDL replication works in AWS DMS (in the case of the two Postgres databases)? I didn't find an explanation of this process in the official documentation.

As I can see the replication task installs `awsdms_ddl_audit` trigger ([here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html#CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.RDSPostgreSQL.NonMasterUser) is information about of this trigger). This trigger intercepts DDL operations and writes them to the `awsdms_ddl_audit` table. I don't understand what happens with these intercepted DDL operations after it.

P.S.

I am asking this because I've noticed that DMS is applying these DDL operations in the middle of the CDC process i.e. it doesn't arrange them with a timeline of CDC changes.

In my case, I update the source database for an hour and at the end of it I remove several columns. The DMS removes these columns when the CDC synchronization process isn't finished yet.

It's very strange behavior.